# How to find out a number is start of a arithmetic sequence in a sequence?

Tags: r

I am not sure whether there have been similar questions before. I am a beginner in R language and did not find a solution until now.

I had a sequence:

`a <- c(19, 20, 21, 54 ,55 ,56 ,57, 58, 59, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 473, 474, 475)`

And I wanna pick up the number **19**  **54**  **256**  **473**

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `diff` to get the difference between adjacent elements, create a logical vector whether the difference is not equal to 1 and extract the correspdonding elements

```
a[c(TRUE, diff(a) != 1)]
[1]  19  54 256 473
```